# Combine two loops into one

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, dictionary, optimization

This code is used to group a string array by first letter.

```
//plain array
var list = ["apple", "apricot", "banana", "blackberry"]

//dictionary of arrays
var dict = Dictionary<String, Array<String>>()

//create necessary keys from first characters
for word in list {
    dict[ String( word.characters.prefix(1) ) ] = [ ]
}

//add words to the key of their first character
for word in list {
    dict[ String( word.characters.prefix(1) ) ]?.append( word )
}

//output dictionary
print(dict)
```

This example would output a dictionary like this:

```
[ "b": ["ba", "bb"],
  "a": ["aa", "ab"] ]
```

The code has two similar `for` loops.  Can they be combined into a single loop wihtout affecting the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sound like a perfect job for a `groupBy` function:

```
extension Array {
    func groupBy<T: Hashable>(f: Element -> T) -> [T: [Element]] {
        var results = [T: [Element]]()
        for element in self {
            let key = f(element)
            if results[key] != nil {
                results[key]!.append(element)
            } else {
                results[key] = [element]
            }
        }
        return results
    }
}

var list = ["apple", "apricot", "banana", "blackberry"]
let dict = list.groupBy {
    String($0.characters.prefix(1))
}
```

Let's walk through it step by step:

- `groupBy` takes a function that gives a key to each element the array. It returns a dictionary with the keys and the list of elements that have the same key.
- `f` is that key-giving function. For each element in the array, check if the result dictionary already has that key. If yes, it will be appended to the list of elements for that key. If no, it creates a new array for that key.

Comment: That makes sense.  I didn't think of `groupBy`. So the function just needs to check if the key was already created before adding the an element.

Comment: Is it possible to preserve the order of the keys?

Comment: Dictionaries have no order. Get the list of keys, sort them, then iterate through the dict in that order

Answer (score 1):

```
    //plain array
    let list = ["apple", "apricot", "banana", "blackberry"]

    //dictionary of arrays
    var dict = Dictionary<String, Array<String>>()

    //create necessary keys from first characters
    for word in list {

        if let _ = dict[ String( word.characters.prefix(1) )] {
            dict[ String( word.characters.prefix(1) )]?.append(word)
        }
        else{
            dict[ String( word.characters.prefix(1) ) ] = [word]
        }
    }

    //output dictionary
    print(dict)
```